# How does stack_height work on inner instructions for older transactions?

Tags: transactions, instructions

Should stack_height be included in old transactions, if possible? Or is this feature only available for transactions after it went live? This transaction, for example, has them marked as null https://solscan.io/tx/P4Bc9P9FX5dZ8inpQTSqEZnYzQWLiZrf2v2R9it6ua84yWy3ZB1h4XBVDF4NgaUE1fNMakTwwJXBiLFU3daFrwe

Here's the feature I'm referring to: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28430

Comment: The feature was not backported to past transactions. It isn't possible to figure it out based on the information already stored in the block unfortunately.